# HTTPAccess Issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have an file called article.php that would normally take a parameter via GET with something like an `id`. I wanted to do something like with a `slug` rather then an `id`, so i could get something like the URL below:

`http://www.website.com/article/slug-goes-here`

My htaccess file works, BUT whenever i load the page, I get 404 errors for my scripts.

`article/css/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Is there any way I could keep this functionality, but preserve my path to my scripts, stylesheets, etc.?

**And my .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a rule in order to fix the resources:

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?slug=$1 [L]` could also work :)

Comment: What would the `get` parameter be? I know mine included `?slug=$1`

Comment: No get parameter, this rule is only for resources, you need both rules.

Comment: @taxicala Oh, so I would just append this to my current file?

Comment: @taxicala Perfect! Ill accept this answer when It allows me.